# Chrome Addon what can run console js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a javascript what help me to publish all drafts videos from youtube,but is very time consuming.Right now i need to go to console every time and paste the code into.
Is there a way to create a chrome addon what can run that script in the browser console?
It will help me a lot.

Thanks

Now i manage to do this,but dont work:

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Content script",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*"],
        "js": ["console.js"]
    }]
}
```

console.js

```
my js code what need to be pasted into browser console
```

Comment: Replace http with https.

Comment: Don't Work. I even can't click on addon to start it.

Answer (score 0):

So i can't do this...
I will past the code into browser console as allways

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).